# Twitter bootstrap side bar navigation affix

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to follow side bar navigation as shown at http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html. However, during scroll down the page I am unable to make the side bar stays on top (and has to be below the top navigation link). This is what I have so far

http://jsfiddle.net/8WzvY/

I am using

```
<body class="site-body" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".bs-docs-sidebar" data-twttr-rendered="true">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
     ....
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot js :

```
$(".nav-list").affix ();
```

look this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/8WzvY/1/

Comment: Thanks. For my case I had to do this `var $window = $(window);
   $(".nav-list").affix({
    offset : {
     top : function() {
      return $window.width() <= 980 ? 290 : 210
     },
     bottom : 270
    }
   });`